# response.body is returning null and response.data is returning undefined in my react+express app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, get, fetch

**App.js in React**

```
  const url = "http://localhost:3001?address="+this.state.location ;
    fetch(url , {
      mode: 'no-cors' // 'cors' by default
    }).then((response)=>{
        console.log(response.data) //undefined
        console.log(response.body) //null
  })
}
```

**app.js in my node app**

```
app.get('/weather' , (req , res)=>{
    if(!req.query.address){
        return res.send({
            error : 'Please, provide an address' // want to get this value in my react app after fetch.
        })
    }
    geoCode(req.query.address , (error , {longitude , latitude , place}={})=>{
        if(error)
        {
            return res.send({
                error // want this value
            })
        }
        getWeather (latitude  ,longitude , (error , {temperature , humidity})=>{
            if(error)
            {
                return res.send({
                   error // want this value
                })
            }
           // want these values
            return res.send({
                temperature ,
                humidity ,
                place
            })


        })
    })

})
```

I want to get error message or data as sent from my node app in my react app. But reponse.data and response.body is not performing well in my react app.

Comment: missed weather here? const url = "http://localhost:3001?address="+this.state.location ;

Comment: what does your response say?  i think you are not receiving any response from the fetch

Comment: Changed the code as : 
`const url = "http://localhost:3001/weather?address="+this.state.location ;
const response = await fetch( url , {mode:'no-cors'});
console.log(response.body);
console.log(response.data);`

But still both return null in console.

Comment: While consoling response, it shows :

`Response{
​
body: null
​
bodyUsed: false
​
headers: Headers {  }
​
ok: false
​
redirected: false
​
status: 0
​
statusText: ""
​
type: "opaque"
​
url: ""
}`

Answer (score 0):

API call should be.

```
  const url = "http://localhost:3001?address=" + this.state.location;
  fetch(url, {
    mode: 'no-cors'
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data)
    console.log(response.body)
  })
```

refer here for more info about fetch API call in react -> [fetch api call](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html)